# Meaning of Combined Notation [ , ] and $

Tags: r

I understand that the `[ , ]` notation extracts values from a data frame in the form [row#, column#]. I also know that the `$` notation returns all the values in a column as a vector, but I am unsure how these 2 notations are put together.

EDIT:

Additional context/example: `mydat[mydat$obsnum == 1,]`

Comment: Can you show an example of where you've seen them used in combination? I can think of a few contexts where this would occur (e.g. `(l <- list(a = mat(1:9, nrow = 3), b = 2)); l$a[2, 2]`), but without more information it's hard to say what precisely you're dealing with.

Comment: ah yes sorry, I meant to include it but forgot, I will add it to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `mydat` is a data frame with `n` rows. Then `mydat$obsnum == 1` creates a logical vector of length `n`, each element of which is `TRUE` if the corresponding element of `mydat$obsnum` is 1, and `FALSE` otherwise.

A subset like `mydat[1, ]` gives you the first row of `mydat`. But you can also subset using a logical vector; you'll get all the rows where the logical vector is `TRUE`.

So,  `mydat[mydat$obsnum == 1, ]` gives you all rows of `mydat` where `mydat$obsnum` is equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of :

```
mydat[mydat$obsnum == 1,]
```

is straightforward if you decompose the expression into the following equivalent 3 lines :

```
X <- mydat$obsnum
Y <- X == 1
mydat[Y,]
```

So, as you correctly stated :

```
X <- mydat$obsnum
```

returns a vector of integers (I presume the number of observations)

Then :

```
Y <- X == 1
```

returns a **logical vector** e.g `c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE...)`, of the same length of `X` with `TRUE` where `X` is equal to 1 and `FALSE` elsewhere.

Finally :

```
mydat[Y,]
```

selects the rows of `mydat` where `Y` is `TRUE` and excludes the rows where `Y` is `FALSE`.

In fact, the `data.frame` subset operator `[,]` accepts either integer vectors containing rows/cols indexes, or logical vectors indicating which rows/cols must be extracted or even character vectors indicating the row/col-names to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `idx <- mydat$obsnum == 1` generates a logical vector `idx`. Now, if `idx[1] == TRUE`, that means the predicate you used to generated the vector evaluated to `TRUE` for the first element. The same holds for a value of, e.g. `idx[3] == FALSE`, only that the predicate was not met.

Your logical vector can then be used to index into the dataframe. So what you are actually doing is this: `mydat[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), ]`, only that you never wrote that index-vector by hand.

As you correctly observed, the `[]`-notation can also be used to select columns in your dataframe. For example, you might only want to select the first column: `mydat[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 1]`.

Now, the great thing is that boolean indexing also works for columns! Can you guess what `mydat[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, FALSE)]` does? Exactly! It returns the first, but not the second column! That is, if the dataframe has *exactly* two columns, otherwise the vector will be recycled wo match `length(colnames(df))`.

Back to the introductory example, `mydat[mydat$obsnum == 1,]`, this will select all rows where the predicate holds, and all columns. If you executed `mydat[mydat$obsnum == 1, mydat$obsnum == 1]`, all that is happening is that R generates two logical vectors and uses them to index a dataframe, it knows nothing about the semantics of that predicate.

Edit: apart from [index vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors), you can also have [index matrices](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-matrices). You'll also find this feature made its way into [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#boolean-indexing), a data analysis library for Python.